# How get a user's keyvault access token from powershell script interactively without az cli or pwsh az module

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, access-token, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I automate processes for certain colleagues. In one use case, a ps1 script is to be executed which gets its required secrets from azure kezvault.

This works really well if the powershell az module or the az cli is installed on the pc, because user-log in is required only initially. This is the case on my machine.

But on the machine of my colleagues, installing the az cli or the az powershell module might not be available as an option.

How would I best authenticate them (for getting a keyvault access token) without having them manually enter credentials everytime at runtime?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Simplest approach for getting key vault secret is by using rest api by service principal authentication.

Here are the steps to achieve the same:

- Create Azure AD and then add that app in the access policies of the key vault.
- Send a request to Azure AD for getting token:

  https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{directoryId}}/oauth2/v2.0/token
  https://vault.azure.net/.default
- Create a new GET request  “Get Secret” with the URL similar to the one below:
  https://yourkeyvaultname.vault.azure.net/secrets/Secret1?api-version=2016-10-01

Here is a detailed article for achieving this , which you can find here :

https://medium.com/@anoopt/accessing-azure-key-vault-secret-through-azure-key-vault-rest-api-using-an-azure-ad-app-4d837fed747

https://github.com/anoopt/GetKeyVaultData

For getting the Azure AD token using powershell, you can simply refer this code:

```
$tenantId = "XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX" 
$clientId = "XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX" 
$clientSecret = "MYCLENTSECRETHERE"

$TokenEndpoint = {https://login.windows.net/{0}/oauth2/token} -f $tenantId 
$resourceURL = "https://management.core.windows.net/";

$Body = @{
        'resource'= $resourceURL
        'client_id' = $clientId
        'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'
        'client_secret' = $clientSecret
}

$params = @{
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Headers = @{'accept'='application/json'}
    Body = $Body
    Method = 'Post'
    URI = $TokenEndpoint
}

$token = Invoke-RestMethod @params

Write-Output $token.access_token
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f98e029a-8c3e-417b-830b-9157bcbecc1e/getting-access-tokenjwt-token-for-azure-ad-using-powershell?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Hope it helps.